# How or where do I change Bootstrap columns width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to lower the point where the `col-lg-` classes switch to the `col-xl-`classes because I'd like to have more control on the 1600-1980 width screens. Right now it just switches from `col-md-` to `col-lg-`, but I'd also like to use the `col-xl-` for the 1900+ width screens.

I'm using JS/CSS only (no SASS or LESS), so I'm looking for the points where those widths are set.

Comment: There's no easy way to add a new breakpoint in 3.x w/o LESS or SASS. Maybe consider [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) although it's still in alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 1900px) {
  .container {
    width: 1700px;
  }
}
```